# Process.Start used to work passing an argument to the program, now it stopped

Tags: vb.net, process

I have a VB.NET application that was starting another .EXE and passing the file to process just fine.  Today I had to cancel the start and missed a MS message about some compatibility (I think) that it would change.  Now the .EXE will start but not process the file.

```
    strScript = strScriptPath & "\" & strScriptFile

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = runEXE
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = strScript

    myProcess.Start()
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you view the program in Task Manager and look at the command line column, you don't see the argument?

Comment: I do see it.  There are double quotes around the program and none around the argument.  The argument is P:\Projects\RunProjects_xp v3.xsp so there is a space after the xp and before the v3.

Comment: Then it sounds like the process is passing the command line fine, but the .EXE isn't doing whatever it should be doing with it.

Comment: Agreed.  But nothing changed from yesterday.  Same .EXE and no updates.  Only the crash and a Microsoft message that I didn't really see, but I did see "compatibility" in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless the .EXE is a VB.net app you can debug, there's not much help that can be provided here.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll reach out to the provider.  I do think it said something that Microsoft had to adjust the permissions or something.

Comment: Not sure how your updates are managed, but when I saw you say "no updates" just thought I'd mention that patch tuesday was yesterday, so it is possible an update could have been applied...

Comment: Thanks soohoonigan.  Good advice!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now resolved as I didn't have quotes around my argument. I should have caught that earlier when Chase Rocker gave the advice to check the command line. I saw the missing quotes but didn't think more about it. The vendor program doesn't give any help when it doesn't find the file to load. When I added the quotes in my app the vendor program then sees the file to load.